# How can I fix "Check email" broken icon in the unity menu?

Tags: unity

This is really annoying me
[image: Ugly Icon]
How can I fix this "Check email" icon ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to change your default program for email. Unity will show the icon of you preferred application for this functionality.

Go to System Settings -> System Info -> Default Applications and change Mail client to one with a icon.